# Increase length and width of Rectangle according to original aspect ratio

Tags: math, rectangles

I have a Rectangle created in my application. Now I want user to be able to update the rectangle size (length/width). But user can only specify the area of the rectangle. From that area, I need to calculate new Length/Width of the rectangle.

I have following information
Original length, original width, original Area, Original vertices of the rectangle, New Area of Rectangle

**How can I calculate new length/width of rectangle based on new Area value by honoring original aspect ratio of Length/Width.**

Comment: Calculate new area / current area. And multiply lenght and height with the square root of that radio.

Comment: Excellent thanks man. That was really simple. I should have got it myself :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

New Length = Original Length * SquareRoot (New Area / Original Area.)
New Width = Original Width * SquareRoot (New Area / Original Area).